# PivotTable Macro Field name error in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am getting following error for the Macro I have created to insert Pivot table.
It was working before without any problem, I didn't change anything.

**Here is the Error**
[image]

**Here is my code**

```
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Detail"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Log!R1C1:R65536C11", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Detail!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion10
    Sheets("Detail").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is indicating that you have an untitled column(s).  Go back and make sure none of the columns in the SourceData range (i.e. columns 1 to 11) have a blank header.

Comment: it works without error, if I only select column which contains data instead of whole sheet

Comment: Understood.  But your code says columns 1 to 11 are all part of the data source.  Does *every* one of these 11 columns (A to K) have a header?

Comment: Yes, I have for all, I think I got it fixed. before I was selecting whole sheet to insert Pivot table now, I select only column which has data then insert Pivot table and it works without error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That can occur with blank names in the header row, or if you're creating a PivotTable with the same name  with PivotTable1 (thus why it worked the first time).

Were you deleting the PivotTable in the past?

Comment: I am trying to automate daily report process, it will be ran with new data everytime.